# After DNS A record change, dig and nslookup showing different results for a the same domain name on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, dns, nslookup, dig

After changing the DNS A record of a hostname, `dig` and `nslookup` are showing different results. While dig is showing the correct IP, nslookup is still showing the old IP. I am on `macos 11.2.3`

The `nslookup` output for my domain `{{domainname}}` is (note that I replaced the resulting ip address with xxx.old.ip.xxx.

```
$ nslookup {{domainname}}
Server:     192.168.178.1
Address:    192.168.178.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   {{domainname}}
Address: xxx.old.ip.xxx
```

and the `dig` output (note that I replaced the resulting IP with `yyy.new.ip.yyy` to indicate that it is a different IP than in the case of nslookup

```
$ dig {{domainname}}
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> {{domainname}}
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45116
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;{{domainname}}.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
{{domainname}}. 1157    IN  A   yyy.new.ip.yyy

;; Query time: 70 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.178.1#53(192.168.178.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Mar 12 18:29:03 CET 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 63
```

What is going wrong with `nslookup`? Is it DNS caching? What can I do to force nslookup (and other tools) to refresh the DNS cache if that was the issue.

**Update**: After about 20 minutes nslookup and dig are showing the same IP and ssh is connecting using the {{domainname}}.

Answer (score 2):

Neither response is from an Authoritative Name Server, therefore the DNS Answer came from a resolver's cache. Before changing a DNS Resource Record, make a note of the TTL value. That is the number of seconds to wait before resolvers drop the cached value. For the `dig` command, the TTL left on the cached value is 1157 seconds before the next refresh.

Comment: So dig and nslookup have different DNS cache? Any information on how to flush the DNS cache of nslookup?

Comment: The answer depends on how you have DNS setup on your local machine (macOS) and for your network. For `nslookup` the resolver is `192.168.178.1`. I do not see what `dig` used. Your OS can cache DNS lookups but if the upstream resolver has the same cached value, then the local cache will just refill with the same old value. However, that only helps with your system. What about the rest of the world? You have to wait for resolvers globally to update.